# React: why binding value makes input readonly?

Tags: reactjs

given this initial state:

```
this.state = {
    person: { id: 1, name: "Liero" }
};
```

when I bind input like this: `<input value={this.state.person.name} />`

**Then I makes the input non editable**. I understand that it would make state and DOM element out of sync.

---

However, when I use defaultValue: `<input defaultValue={this.state.person.name} />`,

I loose posibility to change the person's name from code (e.g. when I want to reset the form).

---

When I manually sync the state and input value:

```
<input value={this.state.person.name} 
       onChange={(evt) =>  this.state.person.name = evt.target.value }/>
```

it does not work until I call setState, or force refresh?

Do I really need to force render of entire component each time the input value changes, when I want to have the posibility to control the `person.name` from code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set `this.state.person.name` directly.  call `this.setState`.

This will trigger another render cycle and then bind `this.state.person.name` to `value`:

```
    <input value={this.state.person.name} 
           onChange={(evt) => {
               this.state.person.name = env.target.value;
               this.setState({person:this.state.person});
           }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to setState() instead of mutate the state? like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  state = { person: { id: 1, name: "Liero" } }

  updateName = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      person: {...this.state.person, name: e.target.value}
    })
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.updateName} value={this.state.person.name} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Two issues here: 1. it uses ES7 syntax, which isn't event standardized yet. 2. It also forces rerender of entire component, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will render the entire component. But you can extract it into a simple component just for your input?

Comment: You could use the `Object.assign` syntax which is standardised. `Object.assign({}, this.state.person, { name: e.target.value })`

Comment: Oh, and don't be afraid of the re-render.  This is expected behaviour.  React see's no change, so no dom mutation occurs.  Cheap as chips.